# Joomla Virtuemart site sh404sef plugin makes the site extremely slow

Tags: php, joomla

My Virtuemart joomla (Version 1.5.15) site when I activate sh404sef (ver 2.1.9.787), it slows down the site dramatically.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You should upgrade to the most current Joomla version.  You're very outdated which poses a huge risk to security and there have been a number of updates since then that might also help address some of your issues.

Answer (score 0):

Check for following files:

administrator/components/com_sh404sef/custom.sef.php   (unwritable)
administrator/components/com_sh404sef/logs (unwritable)
administrator/components/com_sh404sef/security (unwritable)
components/com_sh404sef/cache (unwritable)

Answer (score 0):

Turn on debug mode in global configuration and view a page in the front-end. See how many db queries are executed.

Now turn on your SEF extension - and repeat.

See all those extra db queries?

On standard shared hosting the additional queries can put you over your hosts the limit on db queries.  Optimising queries, adding additio al indexes to your db can help.  More powerful hosting is usually amore cost effective answer.  Alternatively - stick with the built-in SEFwhich works fine if the site is structured optimally.

As stated by others - you are *very* vulnerable to attack - I *think*anyone can request a password reset on your admin account.  Also - later Joomla versions contained many performance upgrades, as will later components.

Comment: But how does extra queries get generated with sh404sef? It should only effect rewrites doesn't it?

Comment: no. Every link in your page has to be looked up in the db and converted to the sef equivalent.  When you arrive on a page the db is queried to translate the url back to a query string equivalent.